# CardView Shadow is not Showing, If More than one card is Overlapping to each other

Tags: android, android-cardview

Below is reference/Output scrrenshot
[image]

In the screen shot you can see there are four overlapping `CardView`, but corner  shadow of top and right is not showing for front cards, (Only Showing shadow for last card)

Update: **Below then lollipop shadow is working**

Below is the XML code for one `CardView`, I'm programmatically inflating these CardView layout, and setting XY property to achieve the overlapping view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/offer_card_width"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/windowBackgroundSecondary"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_offer"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circular_offer"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_content_copy" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_regular"
            android:id="@+id/text_offer_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_offer"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/submit_button"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular"
            android:text="Some content will be there" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_offer_desc"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_regular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_offer_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_offer"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            android:text="Some content will be there, Some content will be there" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_regular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_offer"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Code:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_copy_code"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_content_copy"
                android:textColor="@color/label_header_opac"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular"
                android:text="TEST2016" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Below is java code for inflating the cardview layout

```
private void setupUi() {

        CardView cardView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_pager_offer);
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();

        CardView.LayoutParams params; 

        int cardMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.offer_card_overlapping);
        int sideMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_semi_large);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cardView = (CardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_offer_for_pager, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.text_copy_code);
            CommonUtils.setIconColor(textView, 2, R.color.label_header_opac);
            params = new CardView.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.offer_card_width),
                    (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.offer_card_height));
            cardView.setX(cardMargin * ( 4 - i ) + sideMargin); //XCOORD
            cardView.setY(cardMargin * ( i + 1 )); //YCOORD
            cardView.setLayoutParams(params);
                        frameLayout.addView(cardView);
        }
}
```

Comment: In which api level you are testing

Comment: Tested with android **M** and **L** as well

Comment: On your layout file, try adding app:cardElevation="2dp" to the android.support.v7.widget.CardView tag

Comment: Already tried, no effect

Comment: I believe what you're trying to achieve is simply not possible. That have to do on how the Android graphics renderer pipeline deals with shadow and global ilumination. It was simply not meant to draw overlapping shadows.

Comment: But in android studio layout preview it's showing shadow

Comment: Did you got the solution for this?

Comment: @AjithPandian Added the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a simple answer for this,

Please add a parent layout to CardView, this parent either `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, and give the transparent background to parent then this will work

Below is the example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/mdtp_circle_color"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cardElevation` for example:

```
app:cardElevation = "2dp"
```

Do it like this if you want to overlap `CardView` with another `CardView`. Make sure the first `CardView` elevation is greater than the second `CardView` elevation.